# How can I do wildcard searching with underscores with POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find all rows that have multiple underlines in them separated by some characters, like: `The boys ____ to the store to ___ up some groceries`

I tried `SELECT * FROM "Questions" WHERE "questionText" LIKE '%_%_%'` but this seems to return everything.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Would `'x__x'` qualify? How about `'______ x'` or `'x _'`?

Comment: `Hi _, this is _. would qualify`
`More than one ____ would not qualify`
`Just one _ would not qualify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
  SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questiontext ~ '[ $][_][$ ]';
```

for the case of 2 elements containing space character and underscore:

```
  SELECT * FROM questions where questiontext ~ '^[^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_]+$';
```

Comment: What does the `~` do? and the `[`?

Comment: It's a regular expression - a class that  ~ passes to evaluate. See regular expressions in postgresql.

Comment: This returns things like `She was ____ because she had only gotten three hours of sleep.`. I only want to return things that have an underline separated by non-underlined character, such as: `She was ____ because she had only gotten three hours of __.`

Comment: You add more classes to the regexp [^$][___][^$]   - ^$ means empty string

Comment: Well.. to be clear, I want ONE and only one `_`.

So... `Jack went to the _ to pick up some _.`

Comment: Then '[ _ ]{1}' will do the job for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116137/discussion-between-shamoon-and-dmitryro).